# Base64 code parameter length is too long to post in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, web-applications, echarts

I have tried to post a image base64 code parameter to web controller but it got a bad request error due to parameter value length is too long.

Base64 code was generated by ECharts with data so the image don't have a real path anyway.

I need to click the export button and it will generate a PDF report to download.
Here is part of my jsp function code:

```
    function exportPDF() {
            var picBase64Info = $("#imgURL").val();
            location.href = path + "testing/exportPDF?param="+ picBase64Info;
}
```

But if I use this way to post parameter, I got a "**INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header**" error.

I tried to use Ajax call to post my parameter like this:

```
       $.ajax({
                url:path+"testing/exportPDF",
                type:"POST",
                data:{picBase64Info:picBase64Info}
                success:function(data){
                    ...
                }
            });
```

In this way, picBase64Info can be posted, but my generated PDF file can't be downloaded because Ajax recall function don't support OutputStream file in.

How can I resolve this problem?